# Can we use perl package variable without prefix, with scope only in that package?

Tags: perl, scope, package

My actual code is similar to this.

```
package DEF;
use warnings;
use strict;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw($STR);

our ($STR);

$STR = "bin";

1;
```

package DEF defines $STR and exports it so that others can use it. I can use $STR without any issue inside functions of other packages.

```
package A;
use warnings;
use strict;
use DEF;
use File::Spec::Functions;

$var=catfile($STR,"abc","def");

sub fun{
  print($var,"\n");
}   

sub fun1{
  print($STR,"\n");
}

sub fun3{
  fun();
  fun1();
}
fun3();
1;
```

I want to define a variable in package, which can be used in all functions of package but not outside the package. I dont want to use any prefixes while using the variable and dont want to define the variable in each function.

Declaring variable with `our` makes it accessible outside package.
Above code does not print the variable value as expected.

When i use `my $var` output is

```
abc/def
bin
```

but expected output is

```
bin/abc/def
bin
```

Comment: Re "*Above code does not print the variable value as expected.*", Yeah, because it doesn't even compile. There are three errors in the first 6 lines!!!

Comment: And no function call is shown in the sample.

Comment: Why would you use _package variable_ without prefix? What if other package has a variable with same name exported? Which one of them will take prevalence in your code? How difficult it will become to trace the problem to the source in average sized project? You probably need to look into classes and encapsulation of data and methods into an object instance.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, package variables are global (visible everywhere). Why not use a `my` variable?

```
package SomePkg;

use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = "abc";

sub get_var {
   return $var;
}   

1;
```

It will only be visible in the same lexical scope, so from its declaration to the end of the file.

---

Regarding the update to the question, your claims about the output you get are false.

First, let's add in the `my var;`.

```
$ diff -U 0 A.pm{~,}
--- A.pm~       2020-05-13 15:34:34.110807442 -0700
+++ A.pm        2020-05-13 15:29:17.514556346 -0700
@@ -7 +7 @@
-$var=catfile($STR,"abc","def");
+my $var=catfile($STR,"abc","def");
```

This is the output actually produced:

```
$ perl -Mlib=. -e'use A;'
Global symbol "@ISA" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @ISA"?) at DEF.pm line 5.
Global symbol "@EXPORT" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @EXPORT"?) at DEF.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at A.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at A.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

Let's fix those problems:

```
$ diff -U 0 DEF.pm{~,}
--- DEF.pm~     2020-05-13 15:31:16.070648821 -0700
+++ DEF.pm      2020-05-13 15:31:19.006651138 -0700
@@ -5,2 +5,2 @@
-@ISA = qw(Exporter);
-@EXPORT = qw($STR);
+our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
+our @EXPORT = qw($STR);
```

Now the program works as expected:

```
$ perl -Mlib=. -e'use A;'
bin/abc/def
bin
```

As you can see, there's no problem with `my`.

Comment: Updated answer to address the updates to the question